# codeigniter wont work after being uploaded to hosting

Tags: php, codeigniter, hosting, cpanel

We did a fresh install of codeigniter 3.0.6 in our hosting and everytime we are changing

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
```

to

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
```

we are receiving a 404 error message.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: because there are no controller created named "Home"

Comment: of course there is...

Comment: what is your site URL??

Comment: All your controllers should have filename as well as class with first letter upper case as stated here, http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#let-s-try-it-hello-world

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeIgniter 3.0+ has changed there naming conversations.

In your image your controller name define as ***h*ome.php**. Check first letter. Its should be caps.

> change **home.php** to **Home.php**
>
> Inside **Home.php**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller
{

    public function  __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }
}
```

Comment: i cant believe that this simple thing would fix the website, thank you very much...

Comment: @BeldionBryanBalanan happy to help :)